# Layout in Flexdashboard/R Markdown

Tags: r

I have edited this question because I found a way that is similar to what I wanted. But one thing in the below sample, under performance tab, Can I make the ggplot appear adjacent to the table ? (Similar like this)

[image]

Below is the sample code

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: scroll
    runtime: shiny
    source_code: embed
    theme: cosmo
    storyboard: TRUE
---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
```

```{r}
dt <- mtcars[1:5, 1:6]
Performance <- structure(list(Mills = c("Mill-A", "Mill-B", "Mill-C", "Mill-D", 
"Mill-E"), Performance = c(0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.9, 0.4)), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")
```


Summary
=================

Inputs {.sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```{r}

```


Column {data-width=300}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A

```{r}

```

Row {.tabset .tabset-fade}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Performance {data-height=2000}


```{r}
dt %>%
  kable() %>%
  kable_styling()
ggplot(data = Performance,aes(x=Mills,y=Performance))+geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```


### Parameters {data-height=1000}

```{r}

```

Forecasting
=================

Inputs {.sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

```{r}

```

Column {data-height=1000}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A

```{r}

```
````

Is there a way to achieve this?.......................................................................

Comment: I have struggled with this type of thing myself. With a bit of work, I end up creating a single graphics object with both the chart and table in it and then put that in a single FlexDashboard cell. So something using some combination of `gridExtra`, `ggpubr` and/or `cowplot`.

Comment: Thanks and will check these packages. One thing to be noted here. These bar chart and tables are not related to each other. They are different. Appreciate if you give more info on this. Can I have a sample of your work?

Comment: Wanted to check if you any updates on this?

Comment: @Adam I tried with this ````grid.arrange(t1, g1, main=textGrob("Title", gp=gpar(cex=1)), ncol = 2,
   widths=unit.c(grobWidth(t1), unit(1,"npc") - grobWidth(t1)))````   Here t1 is table and g1 is plot. But not working. Could you please help me in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Background

In my experience, FlexDashboard only gives you a certain degree of control. To gain more control, you can create a single graphics object and then pass that into a single FlexDashboard "spot".

- The **advantage** is the high degree of customization you can have.
- The **disadvantages** are that it is another step and that scaling now becomes a bit tricky to manage.

The table can be the real wild card here. It can be difficult to get the `tableGrob()` object to look and scale how you want it to.

There are also some known issues. For example, with `textGrob()`, when you try to left justify text, it will left justify the center of the text, moving half of it out of your image.

## Example

We will use the `mtcars` dataset to produce a title, two plots, and one table. You can see from this example that the plots and tables can be completely independent of each other.

Then we will use `ggplot2`, `grid`, and `gridExtra` to align them into a 3x2 grid. Our layout will be as follows.

[image: Plot layout]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
```

Another useful package for this type of thing is `cowplot`.

### Create plots

```
dat <- mtcars

plot1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point()

plot2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt)) +
  geom_histogram()

table1 <- tableGrob(head(dat), theme = ttheme_default(base_size = 10))

title <- textGrob("Combined Charts", gp = gpar(fontsize = 24, fontfamily = "sans"))
```

### Combine plots

```
grid_layout <- rbind(c(1, 1),
                     c(2, 3),
                     c(4, 4))

group1 <- grid.arrange(title, plot1, table1, plot2,
                       layout_matrix = grid_layout,
                       heights= c(1, 4, 4))

grid.draw(group1)
```

[image: Combined plots]

### FlexDashboard

You would then take this combined object and add it back into your FlexDashboard file. Here is a snippet from your example.

````
### Performance {data-height=2000}

```{r}

grid.draw(group1)

```
````

Comment: First of all thanks for your time and effort Adam, Really Appreciate it. Will check the code and let you know

Comment: It is working. Thanks. Also one clarification. Can we make the table getting alligned with plot 1. it looks table is small. Can we make table and plot same size?

Comment: That right there is the issue with scaling that I noted - particularly with tables. I have not figured a great way to do that. Presumably you can grab some characteristics from the grob objects and match them up. I have done some trial and error myself just with font sizes and what not to try to make them align. So I think "yes" you can, but I am not an expert on doing that. Maybe somebody has an easy way.